# How to pass parameters from one lwc page to next lwc page on Salesforce1 mobile app?

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce1-app, lightningnavigation, navigationmixin.navigate

I am trying to get lightning navigation service state parameters on next page but it is not working that way on Salesforce1 mobile app. Although it is working fine on chrome browser as web app.

@wire(CurrentPageReference) getPageRef(pageRef){
   this.recordId = pageRef.state.c__rid;
 }

Getting following error.

```
Error: [LWC error]: Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched in 
element <c-lineitemdetail-header-component>. Event name must 1) Start with a 
lowercase letter 2) Contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores
<c-lineitemdetail-header-component>
at Object.logError (aura_proddebug.js:4268)
at ConstructionEstimation.dispatchEvent (aura_proddebug.js:7622)
at ConstructionEstimation.wrappedMethod [as dispatchEvent] (aura_proddebug.js:12985)
at WireEventTarget.dispatchEvent (aura_proddebug.js:9501)
at d.get (contextService.js:2)
at eval (contextService.js:2)
at E (contextService.js:2)
at Object.t.getContextValue (contextService.js:2)
at c.getCurrentPageReference (pageService.js:2)
at eval (navigation.js:2)
```

Comment: Given the stack trace it rather looks like a Salesforce framework bug. Not sure what else it could be...

Comment: Is there any work around to get record id passed from previous page?

Comment: Not that I know of at this point. Perhaps someone else does?

Comment: I am struck on this from last week. I am to fix it asap.

Comment: Sorry to hear it. Unfortunately I can't suggest anything. Perhaps you can try to raise a Salesforce support case? Alternatively, try posting your issue on the developer forums as well to see if you can get Salesforce's attention?

Comment: Someone else already posted this same issue on Salesforce developer forum. Here is the link: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?inputboxform=lwc#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Mobile&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=9062I000000Xlm6QAC